# How to swap JavaScript event listeners at different screen sizes

Tags: javascript

I'm building a nav menu where the desktop version shows sub-menus as drop-downs that appear on hover, and the mobile version has accordion style sub-menus that are triggered on click/touch.

I have both of these set up using the (simplified) code below, but I want to be able to swap the event listeners as the browser window is resized. I've been trying to use resizeObserver to remove and re-add the event listeners, but I'm having trouble unbinding the listeners correctly.

```
const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu-item]');

function setupMenu() {


    menuItems.forEach((item) => {
        const itemHandler = toggleState.bind(null, item);

        if (viewportWidth > 960) {
            item.addEventListener('mouseover', itemHandler);
            item.addEventListener('mouseout', itemHandler);
        } else {
            item.addEventListener('click', itemHandler);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to swap event listeners, you should swap HTML elements...

Comment: Move your `viewportWidth > 960` to inside `itemHandler` so to check for width when event fires, not on init

Comment: I would advise against adding and removing handlers. Check your condition(s) inside your handler callback functions instead, and make them simply _do nothing_, if not applicable.

Comment: Side note: not all touch devices are limited to 960 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of swapping listeners on an element, you should use two seperate elements, each with one of the event listeners, and then use a CSS media query to set `display: none` on the one you want hidden.

Here's an overly simplified example with just CSS, if you really want to use JS for this then you can set the `element.style.display` property, but using CSS is more performant and will work even when the screen is resized multiple times.

```css
#top-bar {
  display: block;
}

#side-bar {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  #top-bar {
    display: none;
  }
  #side-bar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">top</div>
<div id="side-bar">side</div>
```

Comment: Okay, general consensus was definitely that I was barking up the wrong tree with trying to swap event listeners. I went with the approach here, and got it all working in about 5 minutes. Thanks!